# IN vs OR of DocumentDB which is preferable and faster in where condition?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, or-operator, in-operator, nosql

i have two select statements one is with **in** condition and another with **or** condition which one will give the best, when i am searching in a huge collection in DocumentDB

```
SELECT * FROM m where m.gender=1
and m.langPref in ('English','hindhi','telugu','french','Albanian','Croatian','latin')


SELECT * FROM m where m.gender=1
and m.langPref='English' or m.langPref='hindhi' or m.langPref='telugu' or m.langPref='french' or m.langPref='Albanian' or m.langPref='Croatian' or m.langPref='latin')
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried both, and looked at the resulting RU cost for each? Should be pretty easy to do (the RU cost is in the result headers).

Answer (score 1):

For a small number of operators, it does not matter either way.

With a large number of operators, `IN` is certainly better than `OR` in DocumentDB (and most databases), because there is less work for the query optimizer.

Like suggested by others, you can measure the RUs to tell if one is better than the other and by how much.